# session_id is empty for event magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have view product event dispatcher. If someone opens the url from email, session id is not getting generated.

```
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $visitorData = $session->getVisitorData();
    if (array_key_exists("session_id", $visitorData))
    {
        $url = $url . "&sid=" . $visitorData['session_id'];
    }
```

session_id is not available when user visits product detailed page from email for very first time.

Comment: where have you set the session

Answer (score 0):

I was using catalog_controller_product_view event. When user viewed some product from some ad, session id is not created when catalog_controller_product_view event is not getting set. So, I opted to create my own session id if session id is not available in front-end.